Running a powershell script when building a Windows Container results in an unexpected EOF error
I have been trying to configure a docker image to have Visual Studio Build Tools installed on it. I have the following docker file
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019

# buildtools for msvc
# rustup-init for rust installation

SHELL ["powershell", "-executionpolicy remotesigned"]
COPY vs_BuildTools.exe C:\\
COPY rustup-init.exe C:\\
COPY setup.ps1 C:\\


RUN .\setup.ps1


RUN ["C:\\rustup-init.exe", "-y", "-v"]

and the following powershell script
# Powershell Script to install build tools 
# Waits for the installation to complete before exiting

Function install-tools {
    # Install Visual Studio Build Tools
    $vs_bt = "C:\vs_BuildTools.exe"
    Start-Process -FilePath $vs_bt -ArgumentList @("--quiet", "--wait", "--norestart", "--nocache",
    "--installPath C:\BuildTools", "--add Microsoft.Component.MSBuild","--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362",
    "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64")
    
    $Directory = "C:\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\"
    # wait for vs_buildtools.exe too finish
    while(-Not (Test-Path -Path $Directory)) {}
    Write-Output "Done!"
}

install-tools

PS C:\Users\----\Documents\winrust_img> docker build --network="Default Switch" . -t wr:testing
Sending build context to Docker daemon  12.96MB
Step 1/7 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019
 ---> 237fdc0df058
Step 2/7 : SHELL ["powershell", "-executionpolicy remotesigned"]
 ---> Running in 47315eabc649
 ---> Removed intermediate container 47315eabc649
 ---> 607f3135c493
Step 3/7 : COPY vs_BuildTools.exe C:\\
 ---> 4681ba90244e
Step 4/7 : COPY rustup-init.exe C:\\
 ---> aad23faa87a0
Step 5/7 : COPY setup.ps1 C:\\
 ---> 1c71d8abc326
Step 6/7 : RUN .\setup.ps1
 ---> Running in 9a26c3d1bb42
Done!
unexpected EOF

I have tried simpler scripts and I keep getting the same error. If I try to run rustup without the msvc requisites, I get an unexpected EOF after the rust installation finishes too. The script works on my host computer so I doubt its an issue with the script. I have also tried to use batch commands instead and also get an unexpected EOF error. Manually running the commands on a windows container seems to work fine, and I have made sure that the Line Feed is in windows style. I have also tried to run the commands in the docker file and still get an Unexpected EOF error. As such I am wondering what is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

I don't normally use PowerShell, but you're passing -executionpolicy remotesigned as a single argument including an embedded space, and I could see that causing an error.  Does this need to be two separate quoted words in the SHELL line?

@DavidMaze Hi I tried your suggestion, changing it to SHELL ["powershell","-executionpolicy","remotesigned"] but I still get an EOF error.

It may not solve your problem, but on a general note: You should pass -Wait as a direct argument to Start-Process to ensure synchronous execution, then you won't need the while(-Not (Test-Path -Path $Directory)) {} statement (which is to be avoided for creating a tight loop; if you had to wait, you should use Start-Sleep calls between tests).

@mklement0 Thanks for the suggestion. It does seem better than to use the while loop! I am still getting an EOF error, I am starting to wonder if this is a bug with Docker altogether as a simple write-output "hello world" script also gives an EOF error.

Glad to hear it, @ManseejKhatri. The following is just a shot in the dark: is your Dockerfile file perhaps missing a trailing newline?

@mklement0 Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think that was the issue. I ended up downgrading my docker engine to version 4.29.0 and rebuilding the image and it works perfectly now, so I guess this was an issue in the update. I will submit a support ticket and post the solution later.
